# Merge multiple partitions into an ordered single partition

Tags: apache-kafka

Let's say I got a topic with 3 different partitions that grow in an increasing order:

```
1: {1,1,1,2,2}, 2: {1,2,3,3}, 3: {2,2,2,3,4}
```

Would it be possible to stream them all into an orderd single partition of another topic?

```
1: {1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,4}
```

What would be the best approach to do that?

Answer (score 0):

First, create a topic with one partition.

Then, use a single Kafka Streams or consumer app to consume the original topic and write to the new one. Note: order in output topic is not guaranteed.

Comment: Is there no way that a consumer app could guarantee that the output topic would be the orderd sequence of all input streams? Maybe through some windowing operations? This is a theoretical question. I think for this to work, all consumers of a group would need to coordinate their concurrency somehow.

Comment: You could assign each partition manually then move on to the next one when you reach the end of one, but in an endless stream of data, that's not realistically possible